# Getting rid of unsafe code, marshaling uint arrays from bytes?

Tags: c#, struct, marshalling

I am using a project written by someone else to receive some data from a Parrot AR Drone.  A lot of the data comes in as byte arrays, which this library I'm using parses using a bunch of structs.  I'm really new to marshaling in general.

I've got a struct that looks like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public unsafe struct navdata_vision_detect_t
{
    public ushort tag;
    public ushort size;
    public uint nb_detected;
    public fixed uint type [4]; // <Ctype "c_uint32 * 4">
    public fixed uint xc [4]; // <Ctype "c_uint32 * 4">
    public fixed uint yc [4]; // <Ctype "c_uint32 * 4">
    public fixed uint width [4]; // <Ctype "c_uint32 * 4">
    public fixed uint height [4]; // <Ctype "c_uint32 * 4">
    public fixed uint dist [4]; // <Ctype "c_uint32 * 4">
    public fixed float orientation_angle [4]; // <Ctype "float32_t * 4">
}
```

However, if I ever try and access an instance of navdata_vision_detect_t and get at the fixed uint values, I have to use the "fixed" keyword and it seems really messy:

```
unsafe private void drawTagDetection()
{
    int x, y;
    if (_detectData.nb_detected > 0)
    {
         fixed (uint* xc = _detectData.xc)
         {
             x = (int)xc[0];
         }
         fixed (uint* yc = _detectData.yc)
         {
             y = (int)yc[0];
         }
}
```

I'd like to be able to just access the uint arrays like I would normal c# arrays.  I think I should be able to use marshalling for this, but I couldn't get it to work.  I tried something like:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
public uint[] type; // <Ctype "c_uint32 * 4">
```

Which let me remove the "unsafe" and "fixed" keywords, but caused another problem, since when parsing the byte data, there's a large switch statement that does some casts to various structs like this:

```
private static unsafe void ProcessOption(navdata_option_t* option, ref NavdataBag navigationData){
        var tag = (navdata_tag_t) option->tag;
        switch (tag)
        {
        //lots of other stuff here
        case navdata_tag_t.NAVDATA_VISION_TAG:
               navigationData.vision = *(navdata_vision_t*) option;
               break;
        }
}
```

So I still have to have some pointers to this struct in another unsafe function.  How can I get the arrays within these structs to be "safe" while still allowing another unsafe function to cast my object as a struct?

Thank you for any help you can give!

Comment: Unfortunately, your question and code example is not completely clear. Why does your `ProcessOption()` method take a pointer as a parameter? What is the `navdata_option_t` type? How does that relate to the `navdata_vision_detect_t` type? The `navdata_vision_detect_t` type has a `size` field; is that size actually variable? Does the library you use force the unsafe structs on you, or do you have control over the code in the library? It seems to me that simply using `BitConverter` to parse the arrays into actual structs would be best.

Comment: Note that you can effectively create a union in C# by using explicit layout in the type and setting the offset of multiple fields (which can themselves be structs) to the same location within the struct. Whether this might be useful to you or not is not clear, since the question itself isn't very clear.

Comment: Does `*_detectData.xc` not work? Edit: Nope, you are using it as a field. As a local you dont need that. So fix it once on entry or use a parameter, etc

Comment: Pretty unclear why you think you need to use pointers.  You don't have to, `int x = (int)_detectData.xc[0];` works just fine.

Comment: @HansPassant: Not with a field.  `error CS1666: You cannot use fixed size buffers contained in unfixed expressions. Try using the fixed statement.`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, marshalling as `UnmanagedType.ByValArray` is not going to work: we have pointers and not values.
Suggested emulation of union will also fail: arrays are reference types in C#, and using `[FieldOffset(x)]` will not work as expected.

I think you can do it this way:

1) Transform your structure to struct of pointers like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct _navdata_vision_detect_t
{
    public ushort tag;
    public ushort size;
    public uint nb_detected;
    public IntPtr type; // <Ctype "c_uint32 * 4">
    public IntPtr xc; // <Ctype "c_uint32 * 4">
    public IntPtr yc; // <Ctype "c_uint32 * 4">
    public IntPtr width; // <Ctype "c_uint32 * 4
    public IntPtr height; // <Ctype "c_uint32 * 4">
    public IntPtr dist; // <Ctype "c_uint32 * 4">
    public IntPtr orientation_angle; // <Ctype "float32_t * 4">
}
```

2) Wrap a class around this structure. The class should contain above structure as a member. It should also mirror all struct members in a "safe way".

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public class navdata_vision_detect_t
{
    public ushort tag;
    public ushort size;
    public uint nb_detected;
    public uint[] type; // <Ctype "c_uint32 * 4">
    public uint[] xc; // <Ctype "c_uint32 * 4">
    public uint[] yc; // <Ctype "c_uint32 * 4">
    public uint[] width; // <Ctype "c_uint32 * 4
    public uint[] height; // <Ctype "c_uint32 * 4">
    public uint[] dist; // <Ctype "c_uint32 * 4">
    public float[] orientation_angle; // <Ctype "float32_t * 4">

    internal _navdata_vision_detect_t data;
}
```

3) Now you will need a custom marshaller to manually transfer data from pointed data to actual array. Bear in mind that (unfortunately) you cannot use custom marshaller on structures, only on P/Invoke call. 
Your custom Marshaller may look like this:

```
public class myCustomMarshaler : ICustomMarshaler
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    private navdata_vision_detect_t marshaledObj;

    private static myCustomMarshaler marshaler = null;
    public static ICustomMarshaler GetInstance(string cookie)
    {
        if (marshaler == null)
        {
            marshaler = new myCustomMarshaler();
        }
        return marshaler;
    }

    public int GetNativeDataSize()
    {
        return Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(_navdata_vision_detect_t));
    }

    public System.IntPtr MarshalManagedToNative(object managedObj)
    {
        if (!(managedObj is navdata_vision_detect_t))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Specified object is not a navdata_vision_detect_t object.", "managedObj");
        }
        else
        {
            this.marshaledObj = (navdata_vision_detect_t)managedObj;
        }
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(this.GetNativeDataSize());
        if (ptr == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            throw new Exception("Unable to allocate memory to.");
        }
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(this.marshaledObj.data, ptr, false);
        return ptr;
    }
    public object MarshalNativeToManaged(System.IntPtr pNativeData)
    {
        marshaledObj.tag = marshaledObj.data.tag;
        marshaledObj.size = marshaledObj.data.size;
        marshaledObj.nb_detected = marshaledObj.data.nb_detected;

        for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            Int32 _type = Marshal.ReadInt32(this.marshaledObj.data.type, i * sizeof(Int32));
            this.marshaledObj.type[i] = Convert.ToUInt32(_type)
            Int32 _xc = Marshal.ReadInt32(this.marshaledObj.data.xc, i * sizeof(Int32));
            this.marshaledObj.xc[i] = Convert.ToUInt32(_xc)
            Int32 _yc = Marshal.ReadInt32(this.marshaledObj.data.yc, i * sizeof(Int32));
            this.marshaledObj.yc[i] = Convert.ToUInt32(_yc)
            Int32 _width = Marshal.ReadInt32(this.marshaledObj.data.width, i * sizeof(Int32));
            this.marshaledObj.width[i] = Convert.ToUInt32(_width)
            Int32 _height = Marshal.ReadInt32(this.marshaledObj.data.height, i * sizeof(Int32));
            this.marshaledObj.height[i] = Convert.ToUInt32(_height)
            Int32 _dist = Marshal.ReadInt32(this.marshaledObj.data.dist, i * sizeof(Int32));
            this.marshaledObj.dist[i] = Convert.ToUInt32(_dist)
            // Marshal class doesn't have ReadFloat method, so we will read Int32 and convert it to float
            Int32 _orientation_angle = Marshal.ReadInt32(this.marshaledObj.data.orientation_angle, i * sizeof(Int32));
            byte[] tmpBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(_orientation_angle);
            this.marshaledObj.orientation_angle[i] = BitConverter.ToFloat(tmpBytes);
        }
        // Here is your safe "structure"
        return this.marshaledObj;
    }

    public void CleanUpManagedData(object managedObj)
    {
    }

    public void CleanUpNativeData(System.IntPtr pNativeData)
    {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pNativeData);
    }
}
```

4) Use your structure and custom marshaller in external methods like this:

```
[DllImport("legacy.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern short doLegacyStuff(
    [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler, MarshalTypeRef = typeof(myCustomMarshaler))]
    navdata_vision_detect_t navdata);
```

5) You can transform a byte array to the structure in a "safe way" using PtrToStructure():

```
 GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
 navdata_vision_t data = (navdata_vision_t)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(navdata_vision_t));
 handle.Free();
```

Comment: Plz comment what it is that you think is wrong, dear downvoter?